# PHP Forms Logic Issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, logic

I have a logic issue maybe someone can explain how I can achieve this.

1. I have 2 forms that work together.
2. Form 1 is required to get the lead in, its about 3 fields.
3. Form 2 is a pop-up after you click send from Form 1. Form 2 is optional.
4. Client wants only to get one email for their lead system.
5. I'm using PHPMailer, jQuery & Ajax for this.
6. I already auto-populate some of the data into Form 2 from Form 1 into hidden fields to include in the email.

The only thing I can think of is adding some kind of time limit. Don't send form 1 for 10 minutes, if form 2 is filled out then only send form 2 since it already has the info from form 1. If 10 minutes passes without form 2 being filled out send form 1.

If not maybe I need to some how reconsider how the UX works with only 1 form.

The question is, how do submit both forms but only include it one email if the first form is mandatory? I need a way to capture the second form IF it is filled out before the first one is actually send and merge them.

Any help is appreciative!

Thank you,

Comment: read it twice, i dont actually see a question

Comment: Why do you need the time limit? What about a button or check box for the user to get a form 2, only if needed.

Comment: On form 1 have a "Continue" button. On form 2 show them the optional inputs and have a "Finish" button. Once they click Finish send the email.

Comment: If you post your code for what You have tried to do, I can rewrite it for you. However I am not going to wait around very long :p

Comment: f2 launch loads f1 data in to sessions. f2 window closed send f1 data. f2 filled in submitted send f1&f2 data.

Comment: @Dagon that actually may work, thank you. I think perhaps using jquery's unload() function may work in this case.

Comment: or: you could have a 'fake' f1 submit button that loads the f2 form(no pop up) there would only be one actual form and one actual submit.

Answer (score 1):

If the user declines the second form, you can send form one email by observing on an event that is triggered when the second form popup is declined, like observing on an onclick event of the second form close button.

If it was not declined meaning the user submitted the second form then collect all information from both forms and submit in one email